# How to know which method created an object

Tags: ruby

In order to debug the methods or whatever that consume a lot of memory or create many objects, I need to measure the amount of variables by the memory consumed, etc., of every module, class or method, and then list them.

I want to know which method/class/module created a given object. I can write a parser, but I want to know if there is anything easier. Is that possible? I'm doing something like this:

```ruby
ObjectSpace.each_object String do |obj|
  method = get_parent_method_of(obj)
  #....
end
```

Comment: i don't think there is, other than reading `backtrace`, but evenn then, it won't tell you when a variable is defiend, just the call stack.

Comment: To write a method that would determine, say, which method created a certain local variable, how would an argument uniquely represent the variable, consider that variables are not objects? Certainly not by its string representation. Further, suppose the method creating the local variable were itself created dynamically, executed and then immediately `undef`ined. The variable would disappear when the method returned and the method would then go up in a puff of smoke. Sometimes a question has no practical object but is still interesting to mull, but I think this one's just a waste of time.

Comment: 1. what kind of variable?—did you mean “literals”? Maybe instance variables? 2. in most cases there is no _method_ creating anything, check frozen strings, symbols, etc. 3. this problem is definitely an XY problem; it has no meaning / real application.

Comment: ^^ This. Your question screams "XY problem" to me; can you provide some *context* on the actual problem you're trying to solve (not just the proposed solution?)

Comment: I think you are confusing variables with objects. Do you actually want to know which method or a literal expression created an object?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. I'm going to update the question.